# ar_kinect with pointcloud_throttle

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I run the ar_kinect node to detect some ARmarkers. This works fine as long as I do not use pointcoude_throttle nodelet to reduce the amout of calculations.

I started the pointcloud throttle as follows

```
  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle camera_nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="max_rate" value="10.0"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth_registered/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
```

and the ar_kinect node as follows

```
<node name="ar_kinect" pkg="ar_kinect" type="ar_kinect" respawn="true" output="screen">
        <param name="marker_pattern_list" type="string" value="$(find bipedRobin_navigation)/data/objects_kinect"/>
        <param name="marker_data_directory" type="string" value="$(find ar_pose)"/>
        <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
        <remap from="points" to="/cloud_throttled" />
</node>
```

then I get the following error
Failed to find a field named: 'rgb'. Cannot convert message to PCL type.

Using the /cloud_throttled as intput for pointcloud_to_laserscan everything is alright and works.

Next to this issue I asked my self several times what the difference between /camera/depth_register/points, /camera/depth/points and /camera/rgb/points is. Is there somewhere a documentation for the many many outputs from the openni node?

Best Wishes

Johannes Mayr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77631/ar_kinect-with-pointcloud_throttle/) by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics with rgb/points or depth_registered/points are typically XYZRGB (that is, colored clouds), those with depth/points are non-colored XYZ clouds.

I have no idea what pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle does -- but I'm going to guess it outputs an XYZ cloud and ar_kinect needs XYZRGB. I would suggest looking at using topic_tools **throttle** node (http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) which won't disturb the data.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1